# Ajax call in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, for-loop

I know there are lot of question regarding this but still I am unable to find a proper answer which makes my code run properly.

I have one function defined to call ajax which I cannot change due to security issue. This is how I call that function

```
var JsonIQDetails = JSON.stringify(input);//Some input

//pram 1:MethodUrl, 2:JsonObject, 3:ReturnType, 4:SuccessCallBackFunction
InvokeAjaxCall(Url, JsonIQDetails, "json", Success);
```

I have array of objects (more than 500). Since JSON is getting very long so I am unable to make ajax call. Again due to security issue I can't change config file too. So JSON length cannot be increased.

I am dividing the array into small chunks of 100 and calling the method

```
for (i = 0, j = mainObject.length; i < j; i += chunk) {
    var newSubObject = mainObject.slice(i, i + chunk);
    InvokeAjaxCall(Url, newSubObject, "json", Success);

    function Success(data) {
        if (!data) {
            alert("Failed");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Its moving without completing the `for` loop and executing the next code. So I want first it to complete the `for` loop (Probably asynchronous)

Thanks in Advance..!!!

Comment: Explanation of `moving without completing loop` is not clear at all...what does that mean?

Comment: Meaning its going forward without completing the for loop...

Comment: What's going forward? You need to explain issue with more clarity. If all these requests need to complete before other code executes you will need to use promises to execute next code sequence

Comment: How does the server know to combine these slices?

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about! Really. Still can't figure out.

Comment: @Robert Server don't need to combine these slices. It will save one after other

Comment: @charlietfl its Executing next part of code without completing

Comment: @RahulKhandelwal you keep using the same words in a different sequence ... but that explanation is not detailed enough to make any sense out of what code you are talking about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ajax is by default Asynchronous, so you pretty much need to invoke the next part of your ajax call in your success function. Here is a recursive loop that takes care of that.

```
var ajaxRecursive = function(i, j, c){
    if(i < j){
       var newSubObject = mainObject.slice(i, i + chunk);
       InvokeAjaxCall(Url, newSubObject , "json", function(data){
           //do stuff with data
           ajaxRecursive(i+=chunk, j,chunk);
       });
    }
}


ajaxRecursive(0, mainObject.length, chunk);
```

Supposing that the other variables within ajaxRecursive are defined globally.

**Update description:**

- You can get rid of your "success" function and just create it annonymously.